# Force required to remove an electron from an atom

Tags: electrostatics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, atoms

For a certain experiment, it would be useful to me to calculate the force required to remove an electron from an atom of varying atomic number. As I understand it, calculating the energy required is fairly simple, but the force on the electron is a trickier concept.

To grossly oversimplify things, in the absence of any disturbance an electron exists in an orbital around the nucleus with "net zero force", a balance between centripetal and electrostatic forces. I know that if we're being accurate we need to put particles and cats into boxes and do other nonsense, but let's stick with that for now.

So we have net zero force on the electron to start. As I begin to pull it away by exerting a force on the electron cloud, when does the attractive force towards the atom peak and at what value of "distance" (or force I guess)? Assume the nucleus is fixed. How can I calculate this force curve (or peak force) analytically?

Comment: "For a certain experiment..." That's interesting. What experiment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a balance between centripetal and electrostatic forces

We have no such thing. “Centripetal” is a *direction*: towards the center.  An object moving in a circle must have a net force pointing towards the center of the circle, because an object with zero net force would move in a straight line, and a straight line is not a circle. In a planetary model of an atom (which is a wrong model, but still sometimes useful), the center-pointing force is the electrostatic attraction.

The electrostatic force between two unit charges,

$$
F = \frac{\alpha\hbar c}{r^2} = \frac{197\,\rm eV\ nm}{137}\cdot \frac{1}{r^2}
$$

is strongest when the two charges are at their closest approach. People who are used to macroscopic problems might prefer to write the constant as $e^2/4\pi\epsilon_0=\alpha\hbar c$. Note that the Bohr radius is $a_0=(\alpha\hbar c)/(\alpha^2mc^2)$; that is, the coupling constant divided by the ground-state energy.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. So then the centripetal force is the Coulomb force while the "centrifugal force" is the desire of the electron to move in a straight line. These "balance" to keep the electron from heading out.

Comment: [No, Mr. Bond, I expect you to die](https://xkcd.com/123/).